# How to exactly flip an object along an axis?

Tags: animation

I am new to blender and having a little trouble with my animation. I need the legs of the character to be exactly flipped for the first and last frame of the character's walk cycle so that it doesn't look weird when I run that in a loop. I copied the object using Ctrl+C and then pasted in that particular frame using Shift+Ctrl+V but that gave a very weird rotation to the legs. Please help me fix this...

Comment: If you want the animation to loop properly, you probably need the leg to be the same in first and last frame and not flipped. Are your legs separate objects or connected with the body?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To flip an object on an axis, select the mesh, press s for scaling, and then press the axis you want to flip on (x, y, z). Type -1 to flip.